# Extremely Long Loading Time tx_news plugin in typo3

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I am using the typo3 news extension. But in the Backend when I am editing a record or creating a new one it takes several minutes to load.

Is this some wrong configuration of typo3 or would it help to increase the memory limit?

Comment: Please update your question with much more context, e.g. used TYPO3 and EXT:news version, PHP version and current memory_limit, used database, where do you host your website, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Performance issues can come from multiple sources.

It would be helpful if you could provide your server ressources and Typo3 Version.
Is it slow on adding content on other pages ?

Either your Server is pretty slow or on the edge of his ressources.

I compared a fresh Typo3 v11 website with my raspberry3 to my raspberry4 and I had the same results. My Raspberry 3 was extremely slow. You can watch the processes of your server with the command "top". And everytime I opened a site, my processes skyrocket to 100%. My Raspberry4 on the other hand is super fast. That's why I think this is more of a ressource problem.